# How to get Localized folders in EWS

Tags: java, localization, exchangewebservices

I want to access the localized folders in EWS. My program is working perfectly as long as the name of the folders are in English. when I change the language of the mailbox to Arabic, still I can go through all my folders and I have access to emails inside of them. But my problem is that how can I know that which one is Inbox .
I read in one of the answers that we have to use :

```
var folder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

but I have to know first which one is Inbox then I use this command to bind it.
I wonder if EWS has a special code for well-known folders?
I used the EWS Spy but I couldn't see anything common among inbox folders in other languages.

I would be very glad if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more clear with your question ? 
What do you mean with "but I have to know first which one is Inbox then I use this command to bind it." ?

From my understanding to your question, is that maybe you can use the binding you have, and then check based on the ID.

for example this scenario when I want to make sure that the appointment (from the folder calendar) has been deleted, so I check if the item is in the "DeletedItems" folder.

```
var deletedItemsFolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems);
if (appointment.ParentFolderId.ToString() == deletedItemsFolder.Id.ToString())
{
    return true;
}
```

I hope this can answer your question, otherwise just ask more :)

Comment: Thanks For your quick answer, I will try one more time and I let you know.